# React detecting location change to force refresh page (To update useEffect when people use browsers built in back/forward buttons)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently have a problem where when my users use their browsers built in `forward/back` buttons it doesn't reload the state of my page. (Due to the states being set and rendered in a useEffect)

To fix this I have tried to monitor when the location changes (eg, they go to another route) when this happens I force reload the page.

However, this results in an infinite loop of refreshing. I'm not sure how to counter this?

I am on react router v6.3

```js
export const App = () => {
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.reload();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route exact path="/example" element={<Callback />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Let's first take a step back and ask why the the forced reload needs to occur. What is the issue with forward/back navigations?

Comment: Sorry for not going into full depth.

An example of this being an issue is that my user will go to `/application/settings` and make some changes, they will then use the back buttons on their browser. Once they go  to the previous page, their changes will not be reflected and they will think their data didn't save properly.

Comment: And how is the data saved? How is the data consumed and rendered? What is the source of truth? It should be accessible regardless of navigation action.

Comment: It's just stored in a react useState()

Comment: Just noticed, its because the API requests are being cached by disk... Going to look into adding no cache headers onto the request. Thanks for the help :)